# Time taken to generate a Sudoku puzzle

Tags: c++, performance, debugging, sudoku

I am coding a Sudoku puzzle generator but all i see is a blank console terminal when i compile and run the program. I have been waiting for 1 hr but its still a blank console terminal. I am wondering if its because of any logical error OR because it is still processing. Just a heads up, my entire code is super long. How do i optimize it if its a performance issue

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
bool checkrow(int row,int value,int array[][9]);

void producearray(int array[][9]);

bool checksquare(int row,int col,int value,int array[][9]);
bool checkcol(int col,int value,int array[][9]);
void populatearray(int array[][9]);

void printarray(int array[][9]);


int main()
{
int array[9][9];
populatearray( array);
producearray(array);
printarray(array);


system("PAUSE");





}

bool checkrow(int row,int value,int array[][9])// checks the entire row, returns false if any two numbers in the row are the same
{
for (int j=0;j<9;j++)
{
    if (value==array[row][j])
    {
        return false;


    }


}

return true;



}

bool checkcol(int col,int value,int array[][9]) // check if any two numbers in the same column are the same
{
for (int j=0;j<9;j++)
{
    if (value==array[j][col])
    {
        return false;


    }


}

return true;
```

}

```
bool checksquare(int row,int col,int value,int array[][9]) //checks if the number within the same square are the same
{
if  ( ( row>=0 &&  row<=2) && (col>=0 && col<=2) )
{
    for (int i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<=2;j++)
        {
            if (array[i][j]== value)
            {
                return false;

            }

        }


    }

    return true;


}

 else if  ( ( row>=0 &&  row<=2) && (col>=3 && col<=5) )
{
    for (int i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
        for (int j=3;j<=5;j++)
        {
            if (array[i][j]== value)
            {
                return false;

            }

        }


    }

    return true;



}

else if  ( ( row>=0 &&  row<=2) && (col>=6 && col<=8) )
{
    for (int i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
        for (int j=6;j<=8;j++)
        {
            if (array[i][j]== value)
            {
                return false;

            }

        }


    }

    return true;



}


 else if  ( ( row>=3 &&  row<=5) && (col>=0 && col<=2) )
{
    for (int i=3;i<=5;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<=2;j++)
        {
            if (array[i][j]== value)
            {
                return false;

            }

        }


    }

    return true;



}

else if  ( ( row>=3 &&  row<=5) && (col>=3 && col<=5) )
{
    for (int i=3;i<=5;i++)
    {
        for (int j=3;j<=5;j++)
        {
            if (array[i][j]== value)
            {
                return false;

            }

        }


    }

    return true;



}

 else if  ( ( row>=3 &&  row<=5) && (col>=6 && col<=8) )
{
    for (int i=3;i<=5;i++)
    {
        for (int j=6;j<=8;j++)
        {
            if (array[i][j]== value)
            {
                return false;

            }

        }


    }

    return true;



}

else if  ( ( row>=6 &&  row<=8) && (col>=0 && col<=2) )
{
    for (int i=6;i<=8;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<=2;j++)
        {
            if (array[i][j]== value)
            {
                return false;

            }

        }


    }

    return true;



}

 else if  ( ( row>=6 &&  row<=8) && (col>=3 && col<=5) )
{
    for (int i=6;i<=8;i++)
    {
        for (int j=3;j<=5;j++)
        {
            if (array[i][j]== value)
            {
                return false;

            }

        }


    }

    return true;
}

 else if  ( ( row>=6 &&  row<=8) && (col>=6 && col<=8) )
{
    for (int i=6;i<=8;i++)
    {
        for (int j=6;j<=8;j++)
        {
            if (array[i][j]== value)
            {
                return false;

            }

        }


    }

    return true;
}






}

void producearray(int array[9][9]) //produces the array
{
bool isrow;
bool iscol;
bool issquare;

for (int i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<9;j++)
    {
        do
        {
        array[i][j]=rand()%9+1;
         isrow=checkrow(i,array[i][j],array);
         iscol=checkcol(j,array[i][j],array);
         issquare=checksquare(i,j,array[i][j],array);




        }
           while(isrow==false || iscol==false || issquare==false);

    }



}
```

}

```
void populatearray(int array[][9]) // populate the arary
{
for (int i=0;i<9;i++)
{

    for (int j=0;j<9;j++)
    {
        array[i][j]=0;


    }


}




}

void printarray(int array[][9]) //prints the array
{
for (int i=0;i<9;i++)
{

    for (int j=0;j<9;j++)
    {
        cout<<array[i][j]
            <<"\t";


    }
    cout<<endl;


}



}
```

Comment: There is no way it would take an hour to generate a sudoku unless you're doing it very inefficiently. Try debugging to follow your program's execution.

Comment: This is not a question, this is a "debug my program" post.

Comment: i dont think its a logic error but maybe i am wrong . Please enlightened me

Comment: Sorry, I don't know exactly what it's doing, but in your do-while loop, you couple `iscol` with `issquare`. && has a higher precedence then ||, so if you wanted `isrow` and `iscol` to be coupled, you need to put them in brackets.

Comment: thats was a mistake,i have changed the && to ||.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You are doing it wrong.** Your code tries to generate a valid sudoku by randomizing every single field, one by one, checking if there is a collision. This most likely leads to the problem that when a part of the sudoku is already filled, there is no valid solution anymore. Such a deadlock happens all the time. The exising numbers do not conflict, but there is no way to fill the rest. Just take any sudoku from a newspaper and randomly fill a few fields so that they do not immediately conflict. Most likely, you won't be able to complete the sudoku any more.

This problem is what makes a sudoku a puzzle, and your program ignores it - so it must fail (unless the random generator is really, *really*, **really** lucky today).

A much better way to generate a sudoku is to start with a known valid sudoku, than swap rows and columns (always within a 3 line/column block), and whole blocks of three lines / columns, and swap numbers (e.g. replace every 3 with 7 and concurrently every 7 with 3) so that every swap keeps the whole sudoku valid.

Comment: Thanks alot. Appreciate it

Comment: Interesting technique. I was actually considering implementing one of these myself sometime to go along with my solver.

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but how do you "swap rows and columns (always within a 3 line/column block), and whole blocks of three lines / columns, and swap numbers (e.g. replace every 3 with 7 and concurrently every 7 with 3) "

Comment: Valid swaps are e.g. row 4 with row 6. You copy row 4 into a buffer, write row 6 over row 4, then write the buffer content over row 6. The same goes for columns.  To swap blocks of three rows, you need a bigger buffer. To swap numbers, you just need a loop over all rows/column with something like `if (array[i][j]==a) array[i][j]==b) else if (array[i][j]==b) array[i][j]=a;`